# Placing JPanel one after another is hiding the previous attached JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, joptionpane, border-layout

I am trying to create a `JPanel` with set of options, I need to add the options one by one instead of placing all the fields in to single line.. So my issue is, in this process, the previous attached panel is getting hidden or override by new panel..

My expectation in theoretical way:

1. Label: input
2. Label: Input
3. Label: text area (till point 3 completed)
4. Radio buttons with header
5. Timer

**UI Code**

```
mainUI=new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        //***UI Header***//
        JPanel uiheaderPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
         String msg ="<html><b><i>Reset User Password</i></b></html>";
            JLabel label = new JLabel(msg,SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label.setForeground(new Color(4,99,7));
        uiheaderPanel.add(label);
        mainUI.add(uiheaderPanel,BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        
        //***Field Labels***//
        JPanel labels=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JLabel chooseFileLabel=new JLabel("Choose File (XLS / XLSX) : ",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        labels.add(chooseFileLabel);
        JLabel newPwdLbl=new JLabel("Enter New Password : ",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        labels.add(newPwdLbl);
        JLabel updatedFileLocLabel=new JLabel("Updated Passowrd sheet Location : ",SwingConstants.LEFT);
        labels.add(updatedFileLocLabel);
        mainUI.add(labels,BorderLayout.WEST); 
        
        //***Fields***//
       JPanel cfInputPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JPanel inputPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        
        jtf=new JTextField();
        jtf.setPreferredSize(new DimensionUIResource(110, 25));
        JButton jb=new JButton("Choose file");
        jb.setPreferredSize(new DimensionUIResource(110,25));
        
        newPwdInput=new JTextField();
        newPwdInput.setPreferredSize(new DimensionUIResource(90, 20));
        jta=new JTextArea();
        jta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        jta.setLineWrap(true);
        jta.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        inputPanel.add(jtf);
        inputPanel.add(jb);
        cfInputPanel.add(inputPanel);
        cfInputPanel.add(newPwdInput);
        cfInputPanel.add(jta);
       
        mainUI.add(cfInputPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       
       //Radio buttons code
        JPanel radioPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JLabel radioHeaderLbl=new JLabel("Select Reset Passowrd Type :",SwingConstants.LEFT);
        JPanel jp=new JPanel();
        jp.add(radioHeaderLbl);

        radioGroup=new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton forgotPasswordRadio=new JRadioButton("Reset Password from SNET Admin only");
        JRadioButton forgotPasswordRadioBtnFull=new JRadioButton("Reset Password from SNET Admin and Home");
        JRadioButton updateExistPwdBtn=new JRadioButton("Update Existing User Password");
        radioPanel.add(radioHeaderLbl);
        radioGroup.add(forgotPasswordRadio);
        forgotPasswordRadio.setActionCommand("Reset Password from Admin");
        radioGroup.add(forgotPasswordRadioBtnFull);
        forgotPasswordRadioBtnFull.setActionCommand("Reset Password from Admin and Home");
        radioGroup.add(updateExistPwdBtn);
        updateExistPwdBtn.setActionCommand("Existing user password");
        radioPanel.add(forgotPasswordRadio);
        radioPanel.add(forgotPasswordRadioBtnFull);
        radioPanel.add(updateExistPwdBtn);
        
        //Adding timer code
        JPanel timer=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));
        JPanel timerSubPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1,5,5));
        JLabel timeLbl=new JLabel("Timer : ",SwingConstants.LEFT);
        JTextArea tArea=new JTextArea();
        JButton stopCounterBtn=new JButton("Stop Counter");
        JButton continuwWithSNETHOMEBtn=new JButton("Continuew with update");
        timer.add(timeLbl);
        timerSubPanel.add(tArea);
        timerSubPanel.add(stopCounterBtn);
        timerSubPanel.add(continuwWithSNETHOMEBtn);
        timer.add(timerSubPanel);
        
        mainUI.add(jp,BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
       mainUI.add(radioPanel,BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
       mainUI.add(timer,BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE); \\ this line making difference
```

**The images for your reference**

When adding timer

[image]

Without timer

[image]

Comment: 1) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) `newPwdInput=new JTextField();
        newPwdInput.setPreferredSize(..);` a) a better way to suggest a size for a text field is to specify a number of columns in the constructor b) but a password field should be a `JPassWordField`. 4) Consider using a `JComboBox` instead of the radio buttons. 5) The GUI could benefit from ..

Comment: more [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). It looks 'crowded'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I didn't seen a solution for why timer panel overriding the radio buttons pane;

Comment: *"I didn't seen a solution"* I haven't seen an MRE / SSCCE(1). Note that solutions are in answers, below. All I've offered so far is comments / suggestions. 1) When can we expect to see that runnable code?

Answer (score 0):

I have directly added the timer panel to radio panel, so it is directly added to end of the radio panel.

**From**

```
timer.add(timerSubPanel);
```

**To**

```
radioPanel.add(timerSubPanel);
```

Comment: So .. is that the solution to the problem you were trying to fix?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I won't say exactly this is the prefect fix but I got the expected out.